# Homework question: Limit of a complex function

Tags: calculus

> Calculate $$\lim_{x\to0} \displaystyle \frac{\log{(1+x^3)}+\frac{1}{1+x^3}-1}{x^2-\arctan(x^2)}.$$

We have $$\text{arctan}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots$$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$, so $\text{arctan}(x^2) = x^2-\frac{x^6}{3}+\frac{x^{10}}{5}- \cdots$

How should I attack the top part of the fraction???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

To make life easier, for the numerator, let $y=x^3$ to make it
$$\log(1+y)+\frac 1{1+y}-1=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{2 y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ that is to say
$$\log \left(1+x^3\right)+\frac{1}{1+x^3}-1=\frac{x^6}{2}-\frac{2 x^9}{3}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$

Do the same for the denominator : $y=x^2$ and continue.